# How can I encrypt the password in logs file which I used log4j.nosql for cassandra?

Tags: encryption, cassandra, log4j, nosql

I want to encrypt the password for database inside my xml file. I used log4j-nosql-cassandra appender but I coudn't find any way to do that.

Comment: Why would you log passwords in log files in the first place ?

Comment: Because of the regulations of company that i work

Comment: Do you really have a regulation saying you should log password's in logs, or do you have a regulation saying that you should not log password en clear. The latter could simply be solved by not logging password's at all .. What / who would need to decrypt the password you have encrypted in the log ?

Comment: İ guess i ask the totaly wrong question because my collegues explained to me wrong. İ will edit the question. İnside my xml file there is one password i just need to encrpt that part.